# Getting this error using ffmpeg concat in ReactNative "concat imposible to open"

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg, react-native-fs

Hy, I am trying to concat multyple video using ffmpeg concat, testing on samsung j76, android version 8.1.0

```
const textFile = await (await writeTextFileWithAllVideoFiles(filePaths))  
const outputPath = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/video-1.mp4` : `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/video-1.mp4`
console.log(`-f concat -safe 0 -i ${textFile} -c copy ${outputPath}`)
const result = await RNFFmpeg.execute(`-f concat -safe 0 -i ${textFile} -c copy ${outputPath}`)
```

And here is how I create the txt file

```
const writeTextFileWithAllVideoFiles = async (filePaths) => {
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/videoList.txt';

var fileContent = ''
console.log("fileplay1");
filePaths.forEach(path => {
   fileContent += 'file ' + '\'' + path.substring(8) + '\'' + '\r\n'
});
console.log(fileContent);
return RNFS.writeFile(path, fileContent, 'utf8')
.then((success) => {
   console.log(path)
   if (RNFS.exists(path))
      console.log('FILE WRITTEN!')
   return path
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message)
    return err.message
});  
}
```

This is my console log output

```
file 'data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/cache/Camera/f27579d2-1488-4a59-8a9d-7a4e7b6fe716.mp4'
file 'data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/cache/Camera/58130175-bd20-4002-9629-070d0cdd18ac.mp4'

[Tue Feb 02 2021 16:30:45.375]  LOG      /data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/files/videoList.txt
[Tue Feb 02 2021 16:30:45.376]  LOG      FILE WRITTEN!
[Tue Feb 02 2021 16:30:45.376]  LOG      -f concat -safe 0 -i /data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/files/videoList.txt -c copy /data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/files/video-1.mp4
[Tue Feb 02 2021 16:30:45.376]  LOG      [concat @ 0xe2b22000] Impossible to open '/data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/files/data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/cache/Camera/f27579d2-1488-4a59-8a9d-7a4e7b6fe716.mp4'
[Tue Feb 02 2021 16:30:45.377]  LOG      /data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/files/videoList.txt: No such file or directory
```

And the txt file is not on my android device
My manifest is like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
      

<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

I did't see that text file adds its path to paths I have in my txt file **/data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/files**/data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/cache/Camera/f27579d2-1488-4a59-8a9d-7a4e7b6fe716.mp4
And I changed this to

```
var path = 'data/user/0/com.videoeditorapp/cache/Camera/videoList.txt';
```

And this to

```
const arr = path.split('/');    
fileContent += `file '${arr[arr.length - 1]}'\r\n`;
```